# Placing NSDate into UILabel issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to put my NSDate into a UILabel inside a cell. Now I am having this issue

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSTaggedDate rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe41bd157d5000000'

Here's what I've done so far

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 50, 130)];
NSDate *date  = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];
typeLabel.tag =2;
typeLabel.text = date;

[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2]removeFromSuperview];
[cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];

return cell;
}

{
    Start = [[[[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"StartTime"]objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"text"];
    Start = [Start stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    Start = [Start stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
    Stream = [Stream stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString* format = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    NSDateFormatter* formatterUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterUtc setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:8]];

    // Cast the input string to NSDate
    NSDate* utcDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:Start];

    // Set up an NSDateFormatter for the device's local time zone
    NSDateFormatter* formatterLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterLocal setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    // Create local NSDate with time zone difference
    NSDate* localDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];

    NSLog(@"utc:   %@", utcDate);
    NSLog(@"local: %@", localDate);

    [dict setObject:localDate forKey:@"Date"];
    [myArray addObject:dict];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign `NSDate` to text directly, convert it to `NSString` using `NSDateFormatter` and then assign it. The text property of UILabel is of NSString kind. And you are assigning NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a `NSDate` to a `NSString` object. First create a `NSDateFormatter` object and the assign the date to string like this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy''HH:mm"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `NSDate` to `NSString`, than store it into Dictionary as below:

```
    NSDate* localDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];

    NSString *strLocalDate=[formatterUtc stringFromDate:localDate];

    [dict setObject:strLocalDate forKey:@"Date"];
    [myArray addObject:dict];
```